# Search Widget functionality with Activity and Fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have a search widget implementation that I am trying to setup to work in my application. This would not be too complicated if my adapter was being declared in my activity, however my application makes use of the tab viewPagers adpater and activity/fragment structure.

The core situation is that I seek to be able to filter the lists that are in my fragments and because the menu and searchbar is contained in the parent activity, I sense an extra level of complexity.

Does anyone have an idea of a solution/ can point me in direction of how to do this logically.

I am currently trying to derive the position of the tab that is focused. From there I need to be able to clear the entire list so that I can display the new filtered list.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an adapter for every fragment in activity.

Comment: Each fragment does have its own adapter. The situation is how to control the fragments and adapters from within the central activity that contains the search widget.